# all of subgroups of group

Tags: abstract-algebra, group-theory, finite-groups

Is the way to gust that in finite group how many subgroup of same order?I ask this question because when draw the lattice diagram of subgroups of group sure that all of them describe.
Thanks for hint

Comment: You can examine the order of the elements in the finite group and these orders will answer your question

Comment: @alkabary It is not clear how you would find the orders of all of the subgroups of a groups just from knowing the orders of the elements. Finding all subgroups of a group is difficult in general, and I would say that the answer to the question is no.

Answer (score 0):

I concur with Derek that answer in general is NO. However, since conjugate subgroups have the same order, you might try to find the *normalizer* of a subgroup $H$, that is $N_G(H)=\{g \in G| H^g=H \}$. Namely, index$[G:N_G(H)]$, equals the number of different conjugates of $H$. However, two subgroups of the same order do not have to be conjugate.